# I have a problem to install the SETOOLKIT ON mac

Tags: terminal, mac, install, git, hacking

I need your help.
I want to install the setoolkit on my mac, and i found this instuction on internet: https://www.cybrary.it/blog/0p3n/social-engineering-toolkit-os-x/
I followed all of these steps but when i type on the end ./setoolkit to start it, it comes every time these error message: `env: python3: No such file or directory`.

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have Python3 installed?

Comment: I wouldn't trust any instructions which ask me to use `sudo git clone` and have the wrong name for the repository to clone. But the error message you got complains about a missing `python3`  binary. Can I social engineer you into installing the backdoor-infected copy I have sitting on my disk?